# laravel transaction called from other controllers

Tags: laravel, transactions

If I will have a function in my BaseController where there is a transaction like this

```
public static function add_lead_logs($lead_id, $module, $action)
{
    DB::beginTransaction();

    $lead_log               = new LeadLogsModel();
    $lead_log->lead_id  = $lead_id;
    $lead_log->create_by    = Session::get('SESS_USER_ID');
    $lead_log->module       = $module;
    $lead_log->action       = $action;
    if(!$lead_log->save())
    {
        DB::rollback();

        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        DB::commit();

        return true;
    }
}
```

and then I am calling that function inside a controller, lets say I am updating something

```
DB::beginTransasction()

$lead = LeadModel::find(1);
$lead->status = '1';
if($lead->save())
{
   if($this->add_lead_logs($id,$module,$action))
   {
        DB::commit();
   }
}
else
{
   DB::rollback();
}
```

How can I have just 1 transaction? I am not sure whether this will rollback successfully when there is an error.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel supports nested transactions via a transaction counter. `DB::beginTransasction()` increments the counter, and `DB::commit()` and `DB::rollback()` decrement the counter.

The actual database commit/rollback actions only happen on the outermost transaction call. If you're going to manually call the `DB::beginTransasction()`, `DB::commit()`, and `DB::rollback()` methods, then you need to make sure you're always pairing them.

In the case of your current code, if `$lead->save()` returns true, but the `$this->add_lead_logs()` returns false, you're going to enter a codepath that does not call commit/rollback on your outermost transaction. You need to add a rollback in an else condition here.

```
if($lead->save()) {
    if($this->add_lead_logs($id,$module,$action)) {
        DB::commit();
    } else {
        // make sure to rollback if add_lead_logs failed
        DB::rollback();
    }
} else {
    DB::rollback();
}
```

This will ensure that for all code paths, the transaction will always be committed or rolled back.

Comment: that means, I can remove the db:transaction in the add_lead_logs?

Comment: That all depends on your business logic. The idea of transactions is to be able to group multiple insert/update statements into an all or nothing situation. Having one insert/update statement inside a transaction is a little pointless. However, if you had a saving event on your `LeadLogsModel` model which also inserted/updated data, then the transaction would make sense, to make sure that that logic is tied to a successful save of the LeadLogsModel model.